# My shared IP address is blacklisted. What's the quickest way of temporarily use another SMTP account with the same domain?

Tags: smtp, gmail, blacklist

I manage a few shared hosting accounts for some customers in different hosting providers. One of the IPs of those accounts was blacklisted and my customer hasn't been able to send emails to Google accounts for a few days.

A removal request was already submitted but I would like to allow the user to temporarily send emails using another SMTP server (probably in one of my reseller accounts) but still get the emails in this account (IMAP).

Is this possible? Can I have two MX entries and receive the emails in both of them?

Comment: Using another SMTP server is a bad idea unless you have adequately identified the root cause for the reason it was blacklisted in the first place. The host may be compromised or the webmaster may be using illegitimate email lists. You risk blacklisting more IPs if you have not done anything about the reason this happened in the first place.

Comment: @MIfe It's a shared account, it wasn't my customer's fault. My hosting provider said they identified the compromised account but I am still waiting for the removal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't control the IP you should not have submitted a removal request. This underscores why shared hosting should not allow outbound connections on port 25 at all. There's no reason for a webserver to be sending e-mail on port 25.

Your client should have a proper mail server for the domain. Lacking this, they should at least use a 3rd party service (this can be a free one like GMail if they don't mind using a GMail.com address; or paid hosting if they want it to come from their own domain, it's still pretty darn cheap). The webserver should be submitting this e-mail via port 587 (the e-mail submission port) to the e-mail server.

If you want the cheapest reliable e-mail, while keeping your domain name, Google for "outbound mail relay" and you should find plenty of options. Product recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: I didn't submit the request myself, it was submitted by our provider. I just complained that the IP was flagged for abuse.

Comment: Ah, sounded like you submitted it, my apologies. In any case, it's a good excuse to migrate to a proper configuration.